# Visualizing sections of nontrivial vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology

My question is simply: how does one think about sections of nontrivial vector bundles on a smooth manifold, for example? The canonical example I think of is a vector field, i.e. a section of the tangent bundle, or even a differential form (section of the cotangent bundle; slightly harder to visualize as literally as tangent vectors, but still somewhat concrete). I know that the Mobius strip gives a nontrivial bundle over the circle, which is perhaps the only one I can see clearly because of the low dimension, and even then the sections seem not so intuitive. However, when it comes to an arbitrary vector bundle, I have no idea how to imagine the sections.

My motivation is that I'm trying to learn algebraic geometry and sheaf theory, which is explained to me as trying to generalize vector bundles (by just declaring the sections on an open set), but I'm having trouble how to think of these if they're not just trying to emulate vector fields/differential forms (or of course, "smooth functions" on a space in the case of the trivial bundle, which I like as motivation for the structure sheaf on a scheme). Any examples from (beginner) algebraic geometry would be appreciated too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only very few mathematicians understand a concept without a lot of examples. So learn more examples!

I think a great class of examples form the Grassmannians (and are somehow all that you really need to understand, by some universality magic). These are the spaces of $n$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^k$. The bundle just attaches to a point (i.e. an $n$ plane) the plane itself.

You should spend time with the $n=1$ case: the projective spaces. For low dimensions you can draw the sections. The complex analogous are somehow easier to understand. These are $n$ dimensional complex subspaces of some $\mathbb{C}^n$ for $n$ large. Over complex projective space $CP^n$ there is the tautological bundle $L\rightarrow CP^n$, defined as above. Homogenous polynomials in $n+1$ variables are sections of the dual of this line bundle $L$. It is a good exercise to write this down with details.

Finally I suggest to look at vector bundles of rank $r$ over the sphere $S^n$. The sphere is built up from two hemispheres. As these hemispheres are contractible, the restriction of any vector bundle over the sphere is trivial when restricted to one of the hemispheres. The only information of the vector bundle is contained in how these trivializations are glued together. This is a map $S^{n-1}\rightarrow GL(r)$ and closely correspond to the  homotopy groups of $GL(r)$. A great resource for this is Hatcher's vector bundles and $K$-theory.

ps: To see the sections of the mobius strip clearly, see the mobius strip as $[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$ under the identification $(0,x)\sim (1,-x)$. Then a section of this bundle is just a map $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=-f(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving the old question, but I’ve been thinking about this myself. I think one good way to visualize is in the most straightforward way possible (from the definition): via transition maps. It is common in mathematics to define geometric structures via local charts equipped with compatible transition maps. Perhaps in the case of manifolds, for instance, this perspective seems a bit forced at first, since we are used to thinking of curves and surfaces embedded in an ambient space, where we can see all the global geometry at once. This also enables us to visualize trivial bundles on such spaces without much trouble. However, it is also possible to visualize manifolds directly via coordinate charts and transition maps. The same is true for vector bundles.

To be precise: given a vector bundle $V$ on a manifold, in a neighborhood of any point we can always choose a basis of local sections of the bundle. Given $(U_i, B_i)$ with $U_i$ an open cover of the space and $B_i$ a choice of basis of local sections on each $U_i$, we can visualize each $B_i$ as being the standard basis of the trivial bundle on $U_i$. Then we can look at the bundle $V$ over $U_{ij} = U_i \cap U_j$, and observe how $B_i$ transforms under the change of coordinates  to $B_j$.

For example, consider the (holomorphic) line bundle $L$ on the Riemann sphere $X$ whose local sections on an open set containing 0 are holomorphic functions vanishing at 0, and whose local sections on an open set not containing 0 are all holomorphic functions on that set. Note there are no nonzero global sections of this bundle. We can cover the Riemann sphere by two charts $U_0, U_1$ which are both isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, one being the usual embedding $\mathbb{C} \to X$, and the other given by the map $\mathbb{C} \to X$ sending $z \mapsto w = 1/z$. The section $s_0$ sending $z \mapsto z$ defines a basis of local sections of $L$ on $U_0$, and the section $s_1$ sending $w \mapsto 1$ defines a basis of $L$ on $U_1$.

The vector bundle restricted to each chart is trivial, and a choice of coordinates on a vector space is arbitrary, so we may as well visualize the section $s_0$ on $U_0$ as being the constant unit vector field of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{C}$ which points in the positive $x$ direction. We can visualize $s_1$ on $U_1$ similarly.

On the intersection $U_{01}$, $s_0 = \frac{s_1}{w}$. To visualize, we can imagine moving around on the sphere and tracking what our sections look like as we go. We start at $0$, in the $U_0$ chart. As described above, on this chart $s_0$ looks like the “constant” unit tangent vector field 1 on $\mathbb{C}$. When we cross the unit circle (which lies in $U_{01}$), we can change coordinates to those induced by the $U_1$ chart. In these coordinates $s_0$ looks like $1/w$. It may be helpful to draw the unit circle (with $w$-coordinates) and imagine the complex plane as having $z$-coordinates on the interior of the unit circle and $w$ coordinates on the complement of the interior. Graph the vector fields $1$ and $1/w$ at a couple of points of the unit circle. Imagine that as you cross from the inside to the outside of the circle, the former “flips” to the latter. This helps me visualize how the bundle “twists” around the sphere: once we choose coordinate charts, a given section literally “twists” into something else as we move around.